# Problema Api League Of Legends con angular y/o Node

Tags: nodejs, angular, api

Buenas queria practicar un poco el uso de las apis externar, es decir, servicios apis no hechos por mi por lo que encontre la api de **League Of Legends** que parece o parecia facil.

Encuentro en la documentacion las diferentes url que provee la api para obtener los diferentes datos.

Entonces me cree una simple aplicacion en **Angular** ,en mi servicio que se comunicara con la api tengo lo siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeticionesServicesService {

  API_KEY = "SECRETO";
  url_2:XMLHttpRequest;
  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
  ) { }



  getPlayer(nombreJugador: string) {

    // let nombreJugador_tratado =nombreJugador.replace('' ,'%'); 
    let nombreJugador_tratado: string;

    let re = /\ /gi;
    nombreJugador_tratado = nombreJugador.replace(re, "%");




    console.log("-"+nombreJugador_tratado+"-");

    let url:string = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+nombreJugador_tratado+'?api_key='+this.API_KEY;
    console.log('URL => '+url)

    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },

      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }

    );

  }

}
```

Una vez hecho esto obtengo un error **CORS** indicandome que el servidor que tiene la api no permite conexiones externas.

```
  Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/lee%sin%mega?api_key=RGAPI-c1c8536d-10b4-410e-9e95-a3f0670ea0f4 (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').[Saber más]
{…}
​
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: null
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse()
 }
```

**Deduccion:** Lo primero es si el servicio api es ajeno a mi como puedo poner el servidor que me permita la conexion entrante desde mi aplicaciono que esta corriendo en mi localhost.

Si fuese una api creada por mi se que hay metodos para que permita el origen de la peticon hecha por un cliente, pero si acceso al servidor no tengo ni idea como poner un acceso cors.

Si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema o un problema similar me gustaria que me ayuudaran. Gracias.

Añadir tambien que lo he intentado con **nodejs** y a la hora de hacer la peticion no sabria como hacerla exactamente, si alguien supiese como acercarse a lo que yo he creado le estaria muy agradecido, lo dejo a continuacion:

```
router.get('/realApi/:nombreJugador',(req,res)=> {
    'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+nombreJugador+'?api_key='+this.API_KEY;


});
```

PD: se que esta mal pero a una direccion externa no tengo ni idea, tambien se que ese string esta colgando en el aire.

**++ AÑADIDO 1 ++**

> A ver, con un metodo get en mi servidor de nodejs que reciba el nombre del jugador con esa direccion si le hago una peticion AJAX  deberia de funcioanr, solo necesito saber ahora como ejecuto una peticion get a esa url. Muchas Gracias

getPlayer(nombreJugador: string) {

```
// let nombreJugador_tratado =nombreJugador.replace('' ,'%'); 
let nombreJugador_tratado: string;

let re = /\ /gi;
nombreJugador_tratado = nombreJugador.replace(re, "%");




console.log("-"+nombreJugador_tratado+"-");

let url:string = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+nombreJugador_tratado+'?api_key='+this.API_KEY;
console.log('URL => '+url)

this.http.get(url).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },

  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }

);
```

}

Comment: Mira una pregunta que hice hace días con el problema de CORS: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145430/error-al-hacer-peticion-http-ionic

Comment: Lo correcto en este caso es tener un backend que haga la petición al servidor de LoL. Si el API no implementa CORS es porque no desean recibir llamadas directamente desde navegadores.

Comment: o sea que puedo hacerme un backend por ejemplo en nodejs y con eso si me dejaria ? que diferencia hay exactamente hacerla con frontend directamente en vez de pasar por un backend propio ?

Comment: Te libras de tratar con CORS: no es el servidor de LoL el que te exige seguridad, es tu propio navegador el que no permite que el código obtenido del servidor A haga llamadas a un servidor B

Comment: Vale mira si puedes mirar lo que he añadido ultimo a la pregunta te lo agradeceria a ver si saber por donde puedo tirar. Gracias de antemano, ya al menos me habeis aclarado